# How do I pass custom data (web url ) in app server just like in Firebase (Android)

Tags: php, android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-volley

I have an app, whereby I can send push notification to android phone from php-server. In Firebase console it works perfectly well, I am able to include the url in custom data field, such that when the user clicks on the push notification, a webview is opened, which opens up the url (in the custom data field).

how can i pass the custom data also from the server such that when user clicks on push notification, the url in webview is opened.

**Firebase Messaging Service**

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService{
private final String CHANNEL_ID="notificcation";
@Override
public void onNewToken(String s) {
    super.onNewToken(s);
    Log.e("NEW_TOKEN",s);

    FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getInstanceId().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<InstanceIdResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(InstanceIdResult instanceIdResult) {
            String token = instanceIdResult.getToken();
            // Do whatever you want with your token now
            // i.e. store it on SharedPreferences or DB
            // or directly send it to server
            SharedPreferences sharedPreferences=getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(getString(R.string.FCM_PREF), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor=sharedPreferences.edit();
            editor.putString(getString(R.string.FCM_TOKEN),token);
            editor.commit();

        }
    });

}



@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {

    handleMessage(remoteMessage.getData().get(Config.STR_KEY));








}






private void handleMessage(String message) {

    Intent pushNotification=new Intent(Config.STR_PUSH);
    pushNotification.putExtra(Config.STR_MESSAGE,message);
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(pushNotification);


}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

you need to send the notification for a specific device using its Token. and if you want to send for more than one device, you can use for loop to send for all.

this code in `php` will send a notification

```
    <?php

     define( 'API_ACCESS_KEY', 'Firebase Cloud Messaging api key' );
     $myToken = $_GET["token"];

     $title = $_POST["title"];
     $notification = $_POST["message"];
     $msg =
     [
        'message'   => $notification,
        'title'   => $title,
        'custom_url'   => $url
//you can add new data and receive it in android


     ];
     $fields = 
     [
        'registration_ids'  => $token,
        'data'      => $msg
     ];

     $headers = 
     [
       'Authorization: key=' . API_ACCESS_KEY,
       'Content-Type: application/json'
     ];
     $ch = curl_init();
     curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_URL, 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send' );
     curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POST, true );
     curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers );
     curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
     curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false );
     curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode( $fields ) );
     $result = curl_exec($ch );
     curl_close( $ch );
     echo $result;
    ?>
```

see this article. you will be able to do it.

https://medium.com/@chahat.jain0/android-push-notifications-using-firebase-cloud-messaging-fcm-php-and-mysql-da571960aeba

if you have any problem, please leave a comment.

Comment: My code in PHP is similar to yours, but the problem, i am facing is that when i send the notification from the php script, the web url is not sent. The web url is supposed to be passed to the app and then open the url in webview. It works perfectly well in Firebase Console.  How do I pass the url such that when it opens up in webview?

Comment: you can handle it manually, add a new activity that contain webview to your app, and use pendingIntent that  open the new activity and send the url using intent.putExtra. then receive it in your activity and load it using webview. to send the url in the php code. see the edit

Comment: use FirebaseMessagingService to get the custom_url using onMessageReceived method and String url=remoteMessage.getData().get("custom_url")

Comment: It works, but only when the app is in the foreground. once the app is in background, the notification does not send at all

Comment: In 
     $fields use data not notification

Comment: I am using data, not notification, but still it does not

Comment: When use data, you have to receive the notification in onReceive method.